# Using extra var improves performance in javascript / under Chrome 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) Mac

Tags: javascript, performance

*Disclaimer: I'm aware that it might look as premature optimization, however the question is interesting by itself, so thank you for your patience.*

I have two jsfiddles used to measure performance of different kinds of scenarios, and I've stumbled upon one very interesting thing:

https://jsfiddle.net/lu4x/k74oq0de/51/

```
function timeout() {
  var x = 0; // <------------------------------ Using this variable
  for (let iteration = 0; iteration < 1; iteration++) {
    let count = 0;
    let timeA = performance.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      x = map[i]; // <------------------------------ and this assign
      count += x;
    }
    
    let timeB = performance.now();
    let delta = timeB - timeA;

    average = avg(average, run, delta);
    minimum = Math.min(minimum, delta);

    if (++run % 100 === 0) log([run, minimum, average]);
  }
  
  if (iterate) setTimeout(timeout, 0);
}
```

Yields this output on my machine:

```
1000,19.204999999999927,22.00017499999995
900,19.204999999999927,22.074283333333327
800,19.204999999999927,22.13556875000003
700,19.204999999999927,22.222578571428635
600,19.204999999999927,22.271575000000077
500,19.24000000000069,22.486130000000085
400,19.24000000000069,22.41451250000006
300,19.24000000000069,22.209600000000002
200,19.280000000000655,22.322875000000046
100,19.38000000000011,22.719250000000034
```

While the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/lu4x/k74oq0de/52/

```
function timeout() {
    for (let iteration = 0; iteration < 1; iteration++) {
    let count = 0;
    let timeA = performance.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      count += map[i]; // <--------------------- Not using anything
    }
    
    let timeB = performance.now();
    let delta = timeB - timeA;

    average = avg(average, run, delta);
    minimum = Math.min(minimum, delta);

    if (++run % 100 === 0) log([run, minimum, average]);
  }
  
  if (iterate) setTimeout(timeout, 0);
}
```

Yields to the following output:

```
1000,21.125,24.086139999999997
900,21.125,24.086711111111097
800,21.125,24.068375000000003
700,21.125,24.05558571428569
600,21.165000000000873,24.102566666666636
500,21.165000000000873,24.129959999999983
400,21.165000000000873,24.10507499999996
300,21.170000000000073,24.021016666666657
200,21.170000000000073,24.03779999999997
100,21.300000000000182,24.037549999999992
```

I've did some other testing and having a difference of `21.125 - 19.204999999999927 = 1.92` milliseconds. And for such kind of test it is dramatic change, the amount of penalty is close to one dereferencing (i.e. `x.y`) operation.

Why things happen this way.

P.S.

If you put `var x` inside the loop it will be as slow as not using `var x`. I'm flattered...

==============

## Edit

Here is the same performance test using [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/)

https://jsfiddle.net/lu4x/k74oq0de/60/

[Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/) confirms what was shown in previous tests, the difference is significant

Comment: You should totally drop that and try <s>jQuery</s> [Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/).

Comment: @Gothdo just did it, thanks for pointing out such a great lib

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0ek4vV7nEA

Comment: Less than 2ms? Do you really think that's significant?

Comment: The difference in numbers is stable, the logic is counter intuitive, I'd just like to understand why it's happening, what is the reasoning behind that fact

Comment: @Lu4 any chance you watched the video above? What I mean is that - V8  is an **EXTREMELY COMPLICATED** thing, and there is no way it always optimizes the way you expect (unless you're a compiler developer).

Comment: I did, but it doesn't actually answer the question, yeah I should probably contact vm guys but how do I do that?

Comment: @Lu4 contact some of them in twitter, and if you're nice enough and they are not very busy there is a chance someone would make a research for you.